# How reference to a class Room in a class RoomPlayer and in a class RoomPlayer reference to a class Room

Tags: python, import

i have a class Room:

```
class Room:
    name: str
    maxPlayers: int
    players: dict = {}
    player_amount: int = 0

    isPrivate: bool

    owner_user_id: str
    owner_username: str

    def __init__(self, name: str, owner_username: str, owner_user_id: str, private: bool, maxPlayers: int = 4):
        self.name = name
        self.maxPlayers = maxPlayers
        self.isPrivate = private
        self.owner_username = owner_username
        self.owner_user_id = owner_user_id

        rooms.append(self)

        logging.debug(rooms)

    def __del__(self):
        rooms.remove(self)

    async def player_joined(self, player: RoomPlayer):
        await write_to_room_file(self.owner_user_id, 'players', {player.name: player.user_id})

        self.players[self.player_amount] = player
        player.room_player_id = self.player_amount
        self.player_amount += 1

    async def player_left(self, player: RoomPlayer):
        await write_to_room_file(self.owner_user_id, 'players', {player.name: player.user_id})

        self.players.pop(player.room_player_id)
        player.room_player_id = 0
        self.player_amount -= 1

    async def send_message(self, sender: RoomPlayer):
        for player in self.players:
            if player != sender:
                pass
```

that references to a class RoomPlayer

and i have a class RoomPlayer:

```
class RoomPlayer:
    name: str
    room_player_id: int
    user_id: str

    connected_room: Room

    last_message: types.Message

    def __init__(self, name: str, user_id: str, room: Room):
        self.name = name
        self.user_id = user_id

        self.connected_room = room

    async def set_last_message(self, new_message: types.Message):
        self.last_message = new_message

        await self.connected_room.send_message(self)
```

that references to a Room class.

From everything i tried i had errors like circular import and unresolved class if you write this classes in one file.

Im kinda stuck

Comment: You can put the class names in quotes: `room: "Room"` to allow forward-referencing in type hints.

Comment: To avoid such problems with type annotations, begin each file with `from __future__ import annotations` to defer evaluation of the annotations until requested.

Comment: Thanks to Barmar, his solution works great!